# How do i convert List<int[]> into List<int>

Tags: c#

```
private static void A(){
List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>();
int[] a = {0,1,2,3,4};
int[] b = {5,6,7,8,9};
list.Add(a);
list.Add(b);

List<int> list2 = new List<int>(); 
// list2 should contain {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
}
```

How would i convert my `List<int[]> list` into a `List<int>` so that all the `int[] arrays` become one giant list of numbers

Comment: Do you really have a list of an array of ints?

Comment: Yes i do have a list of array ints

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you might be looking for LINQ `.SelectMany` method. 
A quote from MSDN:

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens
>   the resulting sequences into one sequence

```
List<int> list2 = list.SelectMany(l => l).ToList();
```

If you want numbers to be ordered in a specific order you could use `.OrderBy` before executing the query (which will be executed when we call `.ToList`)

```
List<int> list2 = list.SelectMany(l => l).OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

What about?

```
var list2 = a.Concat(b).ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, your answer just avoid the problem in the given example, but doesn't actually solve what the OP is asking

Answer (score 0):

I would use the aggregate function. It is better when you have bigger collection.

```
List<int> list2 = list.Aggregate(new List<int>(), (ag, l) => { ag.AddRange(l); return ag; });
```

Comment: Because I'll have to call .ToList() on the end or you know a better way?